# How to retrieve row data from SQL database - Android

Tags: android, sql

I add data into a database using this code,

```
/**
 * Storing deck
 * */
public void addDeck(String id, String name, String uid, String did) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DECK_ID, id); // ID
    values.put(KEY_DECK_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_DECK_UID, uid); // Unique Id
    values.put(KEY_DECK_DID, did); // Deck id

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_DECK, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Now I want to be able to access each row, how can I do this?

This is my current code to access the rows in the database

```
// Getting deck data from database
public HashMap<String, String> getDeckDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> deck = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DECK;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        deck.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
        deck.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
        deck.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        deck.put("did", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return deck;
}
```

This code only returns the first row, how can I get it to return every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use a loop:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
while( cursor.moveToNext() ){
    deck.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
    deck.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
    deck.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
    deck.put("did", cursor.getString(4));
}
cursor.close();
```

also, instead of `cursor.getString(3)` I'd use:

```
int uidPos = cursor.getColumnIndex( "uid" );
if( -1 != uidPos ) cursor.getString( uidPos );
```

as it's safer